# How to add a size conditional to an effect?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle, fantasy-grounds

The Warblade has a stance called "Stonefoot".  If the Warblade is in that stance, the player gains a +2 strength check bonus, and a +2 AC bonus, but only if the opposing creature is at least one size category larger than the player.

Looking at the [Fantasy Grounds documentation for effects](http://www.fantasygrounds.com/wiki/index.php/3.5E_Effects), it would seem that something like the following should work:

```
Stonefoot; IFT:SIZE(>5); STR:2; AC:2
```

Yet despite testing in various forms, with just the AC bonus, without the leading description, etc, the AC bonus just doesn't take effect.  The only time the AC bonus takes effect is if I remove the "IFT" qualifier.

**Question**: Do I have the right format for the effect above?  If not, what is the right format?

If I do have the right format, then I have to assume that I've done something wrong setting either the player or creature's size values.

Comment: This is D&D 3.5e and Tome of Battle stuff, correct? (I'm asking so that the post's tags can be updated.)

Comment: Yes, ToB & 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fantasy grounds documentation for the [size] tag, it states:

```
[size] = F, D, T, S, M, L, H, G, C, fine, diminutive, tiny, small, medium, large, huge, gargantuan, colossal
```

Meaning that the possible variables you can use are only the ones above. Which means that

```
IFT:SIZE(>5);
```

Would not compile correctly or apply the desired effect, because "5" is not a valid return for the "size" field. It doesn't know what information you're trying to convey so it just parses the end of the statement. If your character is a medium character something akin to this should compile properly:

```
Stonefoot; IFT:SIZE(>medium); STR:2; AC:2
```

Which reads in code, when Stonefoot is active IF Size is greater than Medium, THEN add STR+2, AC+2.

Try that out and tell me how it goes.

Comment: Many thanks.  This finally worked when (a) I did not use abbreviations for ANY of the size settings or in the conditional, and (b) had an NPC character rather than just a Combat Tracker entry.  I was confused by the 'size' setting in the Combat Tracker, which is just a number.

Comment: Good lord... Been working with FG for the last hour and I think this software needs a parser to check whether or not the strings the GM or users enter make any sense to the game!  In the NPC sheet, if the size word isn't first, the IFT doesn't see it, yet nowhere in the documentation have I found an explanation of what order the NPC type field words should be in!

Comment: Glad I could help.